Reclaim disk space after failed run of "wsl --manage Ubuntu --set-sparse false"
I wanted to reclaim the disk space of files that were deleted in wsl using DiskPart.
To do that, I first ran in the Windows cmd
wsl --manage Ubuntu --set-sparse false
However, that failed, but it filled up the remaining 50Gb on my entire C drive. Where did that disk space go, and how can I fix this?
